# Fix Compiler Errors after Removing #include windows.h and Relative Functions Calls

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cross-platform

I'm working on VS2017 on Windows 10. I have a a working FSM with Messaging console application, which however has a couple of Windows libraries (`windows.h` and `winmm.lib`) and a non-standard C++ library (`conio.h`).  I want to remove and/or replace these libraries in order to be able to port the C++ code to OSX. I will remove and/or replace/adapt any current functionality as necessary.

However, after proceeding I get many compiler errors that I cannot explain. I searched for many hours but cannot find any useful references and I need some help figuring these out.

After I remove `#include windows.h` from a particular utility header file (`ConsoleUtils.h`) and remove one of its functions that uses `windows.h`, as well as all calls to this function, I get the following compiler errors:

1. In MessageDispatcher.cpp:

> class MessageDispatcher has no member DispatchMessageW

Well, `MessageDispatcher` has a function `DispatchMessage()` (no 'W' at the end). I'm really puzzled by this. If I hover the mouse pointer over the red curly line in the definition of `MessageDispatcher::DispatchMessage`, a popup displays

> "#define DispatchMessage DispatchMessageW expands to DispatchMessageW"

However, I don't have any such `#define` any where in my code! I even did a text search for "DispatchMessageW" in the entire solution and there are no instances of this text.

2. In MessageDispatcher.cpp:

Additionally, inside the `DispatchMessage()` function two private members are inaccessible (`Discharge()` and `PriorityQ`), both of which are properly declared and defined, and have no reference to `windows.h`.

3. In two other classes that call `MessageDispatcher::DispatchMessage()` I get the same error as described in '1' above.

If I add `#include windows.h` back, all the errors go away, and the project builds and runs with no problem.

What could be causing these errors, and what could I do to fix them?

Comment: Somewhere after you define the `MessageDispatcher` class, and before you use it, something includes `<windows.h>` or some other windows header that is causing the `DispatchMessage` macro to be defined.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thank you very-very much for pointing me in the right direction! Your help was invaluable and I fixed all errors. If you can convert your comment to an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere after you define the `MessageDispatcher` class, and before you use it, something includes `<windows.h>` or some other windows header that is causing the `DispatchMessage` macro to be defined.